# compiling TuxGuitar on on OS X, javac can't find packages

Tags: java, ant, makefile, classpath, javac

I'm trying to compile TuxGuitar (a guitar tablature editor) on OS X. I've checked out the code from the TuxGuitar repository:

`svn checkout svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/tuxguitar/code/trunk tuxguitar-code`

Now, when I run `make` which in turn uses `ant`, it seems `javac` can't find Java packages within the project source tree. I've put the complete output of `make` at http://people.kth.se/~albertwi/tuxg-make-error; it's huge so I can't put all of it here in a code block.

I'm assuming this is a semi-trivial class path issue but I can't tell how to modify the build configuration. On line 307 and onward in the `make` output there are errors/warnings on the form of "some_file.java added as some_file.class doesn't exist", I don't know what this entails:

```
[javac] org/herac/tuxguitar/app/TGMain.java added as org/herac/tuxguitar/app/TGMain.class doesn't exist.
[javac] org/herac/tuxguitar/app/TuxGuitar.java added as org/herac/tuxguitar/app/TuxGuitar.class doesn't exist.
[javac] org/herac/tuxguitar/app/action/TGActionAccessInterceptor.java added as org/herac/tuxguitar/app/action/TGActionAccessInterceptor.class doesn't exist.
...
```

On line 715 and onward some class paths are included, but **it seems like not all the necessary folders are appended here** (the TuxGuitar source tree contains folders on the form TuxGuitar-*some program component*/src/org/herac/tuxguitar, for example TuxGuitar-ascii/src/org and TuxGuitar-fluidsynth/src/org which I believe *should* be included here but they aren't):

```
[javac] Compilation arguments:
[javac] '-d'
[javac] '/Users/awifstrand/src/tuxg/tuxguitar-code/TuxGuitar/build'
[javac] '-classpath'
[javac] '/Users/awifstrand/src/tuxg/tuxguitar-code/TuxGuitar/build:/Users/awifstrand/src/tuxg/tuxguitar-code/TuxGuitar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-antlr.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-apache-oro.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-apache-resolver.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-commons-logging.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-commons-net.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-jai.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-javamail.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-jdepend.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-jmf.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-jsch.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-junit.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-netrexx.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-swing.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant-testutil.jar:/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar'
[javac] '-sourcepath'
[javac] '/Users/awifstrand/src/tuxg/tuxguitar-code/TuxGuitar/src'
...
```

Then on line 1143 and onward I get "package org.herac.tuxguitar.*some package* does not exist" errors:

```
[javac] /Users/awifstrand/src/tuxg/tuxguitar-code/TuxGuitar/src/org/herac/tuxguitar/app/TuxGuitar.java:27: error: package org.herac.tuxguitar.action does not exist
[javac] import org.herac.tuxguitar.action.TGActionManager;
[javac]                                  ^
[javac] /Users/awifstrand/src/tuxg/tuxguitar-code/TuxGuitar/src/org/herac/tuxguitar/app/TuxGuitar.java:68: error: package org.herac.tuxguitar.document does not exist
[javac] import org.herac.tuxguitar.document.TGDocumentManager;
[javac]                                    ^
[javac] /Users/awifstrand/src/tuxg/tuxguitar-code/TuxGuitar/src/org/herac/tuxguitar/app/TuxGuitar.java:69: error: package org.herac.tuxguitar.event does not exist
[javac] import org.herac.tuxguitar.event.TGEvent;
[javac]                                 ^
...
```

I'm not well versed in `make` and `ant`. How and where do I make configuration changes so `javac` can find the packages?

Is the problem so involved that I should ask TuxGuitar developers about this instead?

**Update**: I tried using another way of compiling as suggested at https://sourceforge.net/p/tuxguitar/discussion/522984/thread/3843b30b/#1ce9, so I go to a folder build-scripts/tuxguitar-macosx-cocoa-64 and run `mvn clean package -Dnative-modules=true` but then I get errors related to SWT... this, essentially (full output at http://people.kth.se/~albertwi/tuxg-mvn-error):

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 18 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.herac.tuxguitar:tuxguitar:1.3-SNAPSHOT (/Users/awifstrand/src/tuxg/tuxguitar-code/TuxGuitar/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt:jar is missing. @ org.herac.tuxguitar:tuxguitar:[unknown-version], /Users/awifstrand/src/tuxg/tuxguitar-code/TuxGuitar/pom.xml, line 26, column 15
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.herac.tuxguitar:tuxguitar-browser-ftp:1.3-SNAPSHOT (/Users/awifstrand/src/tuxg/tuxguitar-code/TuxGuitar-browser-ftp/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt:jar is missing. @ org.herac.tuxguitar:tuxguitar-browser-ftp:[unknown-version], /Users/awifstrand/src/tuxg/tuxguitar-code/TuxGuitar-browser-ftp/pom.xml, line 35, column 15
[ERROR]   
...
```

I have the latest version (4.4) of swt.jar in /Library/Java/Extensions so it should be on the class path.

Comment: Does the classPath include "."?

Comment: Try updating your class path to include the current directory (".")

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm getting the same errors with that. I'm assuming you mean the directory that has the Makefile when you say the current directory

Answer (score 2):

I got into the same trouble, it looks like the Makefile is broken as it uses ant instead of maven.
Here are the steps I did (Thanks to my colleage Clément which was born with java while I was with punch cards):

```
$svn checkout svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/tuxguitar/code/trunk tuxguitar-code
$sudo apt-get install maven
$cd tuxguitar-code
$uname -a
Linux acacia 3.16-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.5-1 (2014-10-10) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$cd build-scripts/tuxguitar-linux-x86_64
$rehash
$mvn clean package
$cd target
$cd tuxguitar-1.3-SNAPSHOT-linux-x86_64
$./tuxguitar.sh
```

This did work for me on 3 different computers, all debian based though.
Hope this helps